# How to change directory when activating conda environment in Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, anaconda, conda

Based off of [this Q&A](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/oyHOldtFbdw) (answered by Nehal J Wani) it seems that it's possible to create and then modify a certain config file in order automatically change directories when activating a conda environment. Does someone know how to do this in Windows and/or can just translate the below code to Windows-friendly steps?

```
(root) [watchmen@manhattan ~]# mkdir /tmp/myproject
(root) [watchmen@manhattan ~]# conda create -yn myproject python=3.6
(root) [watchmen@manhattan ~]# source activate myproject
(myproject) [watchmen@manhattan ~]# mkdir -p $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d
(myproject) [watchmen@manhattan ~]# cat <<EOF > $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/gotodirs.sh
> #!/bin/bash
> pushd /tmp/myproject
> EOF
(myproject) [watchmen@manhattan ~]# chmod +x $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/gotodirs.sh
(myproject) [watchmen@manhattan ~]# pwd
/root
(myproject) [watchmen@manhattan ~]# source deactivate
[watchmen@manhattan ~]# source /conda/bin/activate myproject
/tmp/myproject ~
(myproject) [watchmen@manhattan myproject]# pwd
/tmp/myproject
```

Comment: We would be happy to look at your efforts to do translate this into a Windows script. Post your code, error messages, describe what it is doing, and describe what it should be doing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I realise this question is old but I ran into the same problem and found a solution.

Step 1: Find out your environment's directory by running

```
conda env list
```

in the conda Powershell.

Step 2: Change to the environment's directory by using the command:

```
cd [PATH]
```

or by navigating to the directory in the windows explorer.
(You can copy the Path from the output of Step 1.
)

Step 3: In there create the following directory
by using the command:

```
mkdir .\etc\conda\activate.d
```

or by making a new directory "etc", in there a new directory "conda" and then in conda the final directory "activate.d".
All scripts in this directory will be run when activating the environment.

Step 4: Create the script (inside of the activate.d directory)
by using the command

```
cd .\etc\conda\activate.d
new-item . -name set_working_directory.bat -type "file" -value "cd [PATH]"
```

where [PATH] is the path to your desired working directory
or by crating a new file ".bat"
and inside writing `cd [PATH]`. So if you want conda to switch to the directory C:\user\Documents for example, you would write `cd C:\user\Documents` and save the file.

Now, when you run `conda activate [your_env]` the script changes your directory automatically.

Comment: This looks promising - can you clarify what you mean by: "Change the directory" in step 2. What directory do you change it to? Also the line in step 3 "mkdir .\etc\conda\activate.d" suggests you're not doing this on windows. Can you translate this to windows - that's what I was looking for.

Comment: How about now? I added a description about how to do this using the windows explorer. Also, `mkdir` is a windows Powershell command, so I am in fact describing "the windows way". I guess you can use `md` on windows instead of `mkdir` but both commands work.

Comment: Great - thanks for updating this. I was actually able to try this. It did not work at first. But from you explanation I was able to check out the docs. They suggested using .bat files instead of .ps1. When I switched set_working_directory.ps1 to set_working_directory.bat it worked! Please update your answer to .bat and I'll mark it correct. Thanks!

Comment: I am happy to hear that we could resolve this after all this time. I changed the .ps1 to .bat now.

Comment: In my case, using the `Anaconda Powershell Prompt`, the script had to be `.ps1`. So `.bat` or `.ps1` depends on the prompt.