# Possible for different Anaconda environments to have different working directories?

Tags: macos, conda

Depending on what Anaconda notebook I'm working in, I'm often working out of different directories. When I launch a terminal session for a particular environment, is there any way to specify what directory I want that session to be in at session launch? I use Anaconda on macOS, Windows, and Linux, and would be interested in all solutions if they happen to be different

Comment: I don't understand your question, everytime you create and environment on anaconda, it creates already creates a directory for the environment.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to share folders from environments?

Comment: I guess can I simply just want to cd to a specific directory every time I launch a terminal session for a specific environment. Should be simple enough but have not found the way to run a script when I launch a terminal session for a given env

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52694732/how-to-change-directory-when-activating-conda-environment-in-windows see if this can help you